# How to add nested groupby using Jinja2 templates

Tags: python, flask, filter, group-by, jinja2

I have a view in which I am printing `last_name` and `mrn` of patients. Since a particular diagnosis can be given multiple times for a patient, I would like to group by patient and diagnosis.

I Googled like crazy and could not find anything on applying nested groupby filters like I am trying to achieve (which I find hard to believe, since my use case is not that uncommon).

In any case, I have tried various nesting strategies and the best I could come up with was:

```
{% for item in patient_diagnoses  %}
    {% for group in patient_diagnoses | groupby('dx_name') %}
        {{ group.grouper }}: {{ group.list | groupby('mrn') }}

    {% endfor %}

    mrn: {{ item.mrn }} dx: {{ item.dx_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

This works, kind of, but instead of a single row output, I am getting 2 rows (I checked and the particular patient has 8 diagnoses of the same type). I am hoping that my implementation of this is just screwy due to not being very experienced with Jinja2.

**EDIT**

The data (returned from SQLAlchemy) look like, with the only difference being the `dx_date`:

```
{'dx_name': u'Atrial septal defect', 'first_name': u'Test', 'last_name': u'Patient', 'mrn': u'12345678', 'dx_date': u'1/28/2015'}

{'dx_name': u'Atrial septal defect', 'first_name': u'Test', 'last_name': u'Patient', 'mrn': u'12345678', 'dx_date': u'1/28/2014'}

{'dx_name': u'Atrial septal defect', 'first_name': u'Test', 'last_name': u'Patient', 'mrn': u'12345678', 'dx_date': u'1/28/2013'}

{'dx_name': u'Atrial septal defect', 'first_name': u'Test', 'last_name': u'Patient', 'mrn': u'12345678', 'dx_date': u'1/28/2012'}

{'dx_name': u'Atrial septal defect', 'first_name': u'Test', 'last_name': u'Patient', 'mrn': u'12345678', 'dx_date': u'1/28/2011'}
```

...

Thus, I would like to see just one instance being rendered on my template:

```
mrn: 12345678 dx: Atrial septal defect
```

But, it's printing two of these, not one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of futzing around, I got it:

```
{% for group in value_columns | groupby('dx_name') %}
    {% for group2 in group.list | groupby('mrn') %}
       mrn: {{ group2.grouper }} dx: {{ group.grouper }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

gives me the desired single instance. The stuff on the bottom was a distraction.